# My ViewPager Fragment data of recyclerview and layout disappear after coming back from a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm getting the object from `modelView` as you guys see. 
Every thing is perfectly working apart from my viewpager fragment when I first come to my pager fragment it shows data when I go through forward and then come backward it disappears my data and my layout structure.
My `viewModel` have data always have a data but my `recyclerview` is not showing it.

BrandFragment is a base fragment having viewpager in it.

**BrandFragment :**

```
public class BrandFragment extends Fragment {


@BindView(R.id.brandtablayout)
TabLayout brandtablayout;
@BindView(R.id.brandpager)
ViewPager brandpager;
@BindView(R.id.backgroundImage)
ImageView backgroundImage;
@BindView(R.id.brandIcon)
CircleImageView brandIcon;
@BindView(R.id.brandName)
TextView brandName;
@BindView(R.id.brandTagLine)
TextView brandTagLine;
@BindView(R.id.brandRatingBar)
RatingBar brandRatingBar;

@BindView(R.id.noInternet)
ImageView noInternet;

private Brand brand;
int chipId;
private KProgressHUD mProgressBar;
private ShareViewModel shareViewModel;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_brand, container, false);
    brandpager = view.findViewById(R.id.brandpager);
    brandtablayout = view.findViewById(R.id.brandtablayout);

    backgroundImage = view.findViewById(R.id.backgroundImage);
    brandIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.brandIcon);
    brandName = view.findViewById(R.id.brandName);
    brandTagLine= view.findViewById(R.id.brandTagLine);
    brandRatingBar = view.findViewById(R.id.brandRatingBar);
    noInternet = view.findViewById(R.id.noInternet);


    brandtablayout.addTab(brandtablayout.newTab().setText("Product"));
    brandtablayout.addTab(brandtablayout.newTab().setText("Profile"));

    brandtablayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    BrandProfileViewPagerAdapter brandProfileAdapter = new BrandProfileViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), brandtablayout.getTabCount());
    brandpager.setAdapter(brandProfileAdapter);
    brandtablayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            brandpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });


    progressbar("Getting Brand Detail","Please wait...");




    return view;
}

private void getBrandDetails() {
    WebServiceFactory.getInstance().getBrandDetails(chipId).enqueue(new Callback<Brand>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Brand> call, Response<Brand> response) {
            if (response.body().getFlag() == 1) {
                brand = response.body();
                shareViewModel.setBrandProductsMutableLiveData(brand.getBrandProducts());
                shareViewModel.setBrandSpecificationsMutableLiveData(brand.getBrandSpecifications());
                brandProfileDetails();
                mProgressBar.dismiss();
            }else {
                mProgressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Brand> call, Throwable t) {
            mProgressBar.dismiss();
        }
    });


}

private void brandProfileDetails(){
    if (brand.getBrandSpecifications() != null){
        brandRatingBar.setRating(brand.getBrandSpecifications().getBrandRates());
        brandName.setText(brand.getBrandSpecifications().getBrandName());
        Picasso.get().load(AppConstants.imagePath(brand.getBrandSpecifications().getBrandBg())).into(backgroundImage);
        brandTagLine.setText(brand.getBrandSpecifications().getBrandSlogan());
        Picasso.get().load(AppConstants.imagePath(brand.getBrandSpecifications().getBrandIcon())).into(brandIcon);
    }

    mProgressBar.dismiss();

}

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated (@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        shareViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity) requireActivity()).get(ShareViewModel.class);
        shareViewModel.getChipId().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer id) {
                chipId =id;

                if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getContext())) {
                    // Internet Available...
                    noInternet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    getBrandDetails();
                } else {
                    noInternet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mProgressBar.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Check your internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // Internet Not Available...
                }

            }
        });
    }



private void progressbar(String title, String detail){
    mProgressBar = KProgressHUD.create(getContext())
            .setStyle(KProgressHUD.Style.SPIN_INDETERMINATE)
            .setLabel(title)
            .setDetailsLabel(detail)
            .setCancellable(false)
            .setAnimationSpeed(2)
            .setDimAmount(0.5f)
            .show();
}


}
```

**BrandProductFragment :**

```
public class BrandProductFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerviewOnClickInterface, CategoryRecyclerviewInterface, ChipsInterface, MyButtonClickListener {


int tabCount;
@BindView(R.id.brandPopularProduct)
TextView brandPopularProduct;
@BindView(R.id.brandNewProduct)
TextView brnadNewProduct;
@BindView(R.id.brandHighestProduct)
TextView brandHighestProduct;
@BindView(R.id.brandLowestProduct)
TextView brandLowestProduct;
@BindView(R.id.brandProductRecyclerview)
RecyclerView brandProductRecyclerview;
BrandProfilePopularAdapter brandProfilePopularAdapter;
BrandNewReleaseAdapter brandNewReleaseAdapter;
BrandProductHighestAdapter brandProductHighestAdapter;
BrandLowestAdapter brandLowestAdapter;
BrandProducts brandProductData;

ShareViewModel shareViewModel;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_brand_product, container, false);

    tabCount = 0;




    brandPopularProduct = view.findViewById(R.id.brandPopularProduct);
    brnadNewProduct = view.findViewById(R.id.brandNewProduct);
    brandHighestProduct = view.findViewById(R.id.brandHighestProduct);
    brandLowestProduct = view.findViewById(R.id.brandLowestProduct);
    brandProductRecyclerview = view.findViewById(R.id.brandProductRecyclerview);


    buttonOnClick();

    return view;
}

private void buttonOnClick() {

    brandPopularProduct.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        tabCount = 1;
        tabSelector();
        if (brandProductData != null) {
            getBrandProductPopular(brandProductData);
        }

    });
    brnadNewProduct.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        tabCount = 2;
        tabSelector();

        if (brandProductData != null) {
            getBrandProductNewRelease();
        }

    });
    brandHighestProduct.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        tabCount = 3;
        tabSelector();
        if (brandProductData != null) {
            getBrandProductHighest();
        }

    });
    brandLowestProduct.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        tabCount = 4;
        tabSelector();
        if (brandProductData != null) {
            getBrandProductLowest();
        }

    });


}

private void tabSelector() {
    if (tabCount == 1) {
        brandPopularProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor));
        brandPopularProduct.setTextSize(20);
        brnadNewProduct.setTextSize(18);
        brandLowestProduct.setTextSize(18);
        brandHighestProduct.setTextSize(18);
        brnadNewProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor2));
        brandHighestProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor2));
        brandLowestProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor2));

    } else if (tabCount == 2) {
        brnadNewProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor));
        brandPopularProduct.setTextSize(18);
        brnadNewProduct.setTextSize(20);
        brandLowestProduct.setTextSize(18);
        brandHighestProduct.setTextSize(18);
        brandPopularProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor2));
        brandHighestProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor2));
        brandLowestProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor2));


    } else if (tabCount == 3) {
        brandHighestProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor));
        brandPopularProduct.setTextSize(18);
        brnadNewProduct.setTextSize(18);
        brandLowestProduct.setTextSize(18);
        brandHighestProduct.setTextSize(20);
        brnadNewProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor2));
        brandPopularProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor2));
        brandLowestProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor2));

    } else if (tabCount == 4) {
        brandLowestProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor));
        brandPopularProduct.setTextSize(18);
        brnadNewProduct.setTextSize(18);
        brandLowestProduct.setTextSize(20);
        brandHighestProduct.setTextSize(18);
        brnadNewProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor2));
        brandHighestProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor2));
        brandPopularProduct.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fontColor2));

    }

}

private void getBrandProductPopular(BrandProducts brandProductData) {
    if (brandProductData.getPOPULARPRODUCTS() != null){
        brandProfilePopularAdapter = new BrandProfilePopularAdapter(getContext(), brandProductData.getPOPULARPRODUCTS(), this);
        GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
        brandProductRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        brandProductRecyclerview.setAdapter(brandProfilePopularAdapter);
        recyclerviewAnimation(brandProductRecyclerview);
    }

}

private void getBrandProductNewRelease() {
    if ( brandProductData.getNEWRELEASEPRODUCTS() != null){
        brandNewReleaseAdapter = new BrandNewReleaseAdapter(getContext(), brandProductData.getNEWRELEASEPRODUCTS(), this);
        GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
        brandProductRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        brandProductRecyclerview.setAdapter(brandNewReleaseAdapter);
        recyclerviewAnimation(brandProductRecyclerview);
    }

}


private void getBrandProductHighest() {
    if (brandProductData.getHIGHESTPRODUCTS() != null){
        brandProductHighestAdapter = new BrandProductHighestAdapter(getContext(), brandProductData.getHIGHESTPRODUCTS(), this);
        GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
        brandProductRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        brandProductRecyclerview.setAdapter(brandProductHighestAdapter);
        recyclerviewAnimation(brandProductRecyclerview);
    }

}

private void getBrandProductLowest() {
    if ( brandProductData.getLOWESTPRODUCTS() != null){
        brandLowestAdapter = new BrandLowestAdapter(getContext(), brandProductData.getLOWESTPRODUCTS(), this);
        GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
        brandProductRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        brandProductRecyclerview.setAdapter(brandLowestAdapter);
        recyclerviewAnimation(brandProductRecyclerview);
    }

}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    shareViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of((FragmentActivity) getContext()).get(ShareViewModel.class);
    shareViewModel.getBrandProduct().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<BrandProducts>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(BrandProducts brandProducts) {
            Log.e("getBrands", brandProducts.toString());
            brandProductData = brandProducts;

            getBrandProductPopular(brandProductData);

        }
    });

}

private void recyclerviewAnimation(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    Context context = recyclerView.getContext();
    LayoutAnimationController layoutAnimationController = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_animation_fall_down);
    recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(layoutAnimationController);
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
}

int productId;

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    shareViewModel.setProductIdMutable(brandProductData.getPOPULARPRODUCTS().get(position).getProductId());
    fragmentTransaction();
}


@Override
public void onItemClickCategory(int position) {
    shareViewModel.setProductIdMutable(brandProductData.getNEWRELEASEPRODUCTS().get(position).getProductId());
    fragmentTransaction();
}

@Override
public void onChipItemClick(int position) {
    shareViewModel.setProductIdMutable(brandProductData.getHIGHESTPRODUCTS().get(position).getProductId());
    fragmentTransaction();
}

@Override
public void onclick(int position) {

    shareViewModel.setProductIdMutable(brandProductData.getLOWESTPRODUCTS().get(position).getProductId());
    fragmentTransaction();

}


private void fragmentTransaction() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("BrandProduct", "brand");
    PreviewProductFragment previewProductFragment = new PreviewProductFragment();
    previewProductFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack("");
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_right_to_left, R.anim.exit_right_to_left);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.tabbed_framelayout, previewProductFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}


}
```

**BrandProfileViewPagerAdapter  this is my viewPager Adapter :**

```
 public class BrandProfileViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private int tabCount;
public BrandProfileViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int tabs) {
    super(fm, tabs);
    this.tabCount=tabs;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            BrandProductFragment brandProductFragment = new BrandProductFragment();
            return brandProductFragment;
        case 1:
            BrandProfileFragment brandProfileFragment= new BrandProfileFragment();
            return brandProfileFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabCount;
}
}
```

**Before :**

[image]

**After :** 
[image]

Comment: Hello ! better to format your code and explain more your issue.

Comment: format ? 
let me explain my code.
1) BrandFragment :This is the fragment where my viewpager and Api called
2) BrandProductFragment : this fragment is a viewpager Fragment and this fragment get the data from BrandFragment through ViewModel

my problem is when first come to my fragmemt(BrandProductFragment) and then select any item to preview(Open new Frgament that shows the item details) when i comeback  to my previous(BrandProductFragment)  screen my recyclerview and options(popular,lowest etc) disappera until i go back 1 step(Home) then come back to Brand Profile again . . .

Comment: as you can see above how my fragment + viewPager behave :|